# Excel spreadsheet to extract data from CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I have an excel spreadsheet ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XDHU.jpg)) with different MLB teams on it. I want to take a CSV of information ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lae9K.jpg)) and match the wins up to each team I have in my spreadsheet.

I was thinking of using an 'if' statement to try to match the different teams and their wins totals taken from the CSV data... Any ideas?!

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little more to work with. Show us what your CSV looks like, and what you want your imagined code to achieve. When you refer to "each team I have in my spreadsheet", is that a separate data set? If so you'll need to show us that too. As things stand, my guess is that you may get some mileage with SUMIFS and COUNTIFS functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the CSV info, it's a complete listing of the standings of the MLB - I am only really interested in matching up this CSV with a spreadsheet that I mentioned before. This CSV in the second picture would be the data set.

Comment: Second picture? I can only see one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already added spreadsheet I started making.. here it is.. I just would like to match teams with wins using the CSV I first posted in a pic using an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: As things stand these spreadsheets have no data in common. You'll need to have a table which relates the three character codes into the names (or vice-versa). I'll make a fuller response shortly.

Comment: Eureka, everything clicked and the two spreadsheets starting talking to one another! thanks for the info. Now I want to get fancy and total the columns for each team, and maybe add a 'LAST 20' games feature to the list as well which I will be able to do with 'VLOOKUP' - thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that you only want to add the number of wins next to each team, I'd take the following approach:

1. Add a second tab in your workbook called `MLB Standings`, and use this to store the data from CSV of complete standings. You may find it helpful to use Excel's "text to columns" feature for this.
2. In the cell to the right of each of your "picked teams", add the three letter code used for that team in the `MLB Standings` tab. I'm going to assume this is column B.
3. In the next cell across, column C, for each team add the formula.

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(Bn,'MLB Standings'!$B:$AA,4,FALSE)
   ```

   Where the `n` is the row you're on in the "Picked Teams" sheet. I explain the parts of this formula below.
4. Copy and paste the formula next to the 3 letter codes for each picked team.
5. You should now have a complete set of how many wins each of the teams has achieved.
6. Obviously, you'll need to periodically update your `MLB Standings` sheet. Don't delete the sheet, and don't delete the the rows/columns. That will cause the formulas in the first sheet to break. Instead, highlight the data tap the delete key <kbd>DEL</kbd>. This clears the cells, leaving any formulas pointing at them intact. Now add your updated standings to the `MLB Standings` sheet.
7. Your figures in the "Picked Teams" sheet should update automatically. (Unless you've turned off automatic calculations, in which case press <kbd>F9</kbd>.)

**VLOOKUP Explained**

We're using the formula below, where `Bn` is a cell containing one of your three character codes.

```
=VLOOKUP(Bn,'MLB Standings'!$B:$AA,4,FALSE)
```

*1st Parameter - Lookup Value*: This is the value, or cell containing the value, you have in common between the two data sets. You are going to look this up in the other data set. In our case it's the three character code denoting the team.

*2nd Parameter - Table Array*: This is the data set where we want to look up the first parameter and from which we wish to return data on the matching row. The match has to be found in the first column of the *Table Array*, which is why we're starting at column `B` of the `MLB Standings`. I've added `$` signs to the address to stop it changing should you need to copy it to cells in another column.

*3rd Parameter - Col Index Num*: If you count from the first column of the `Table Array` across to the column from which to return data, the number you finish upon will be what you need. In our case, wins are the fourth column into our data set (since we've omitted column A). Technically, since we're only going to column 4, you could change your *Table Array* to `$B:$E`, but then if you wanted to return other columns from the data in addition to wins, you'd need to make amendments.

*4th Parameter - Range Lookup*: We want to find an exact match in the relevant column of our *Table Array*. So we specify `FALSE`. You can also use `0` as a short-hand. There are some cases where you don't want to do an exact match when you could specifiy `TRUE` or `1` (or omit the fourth parameter, as this is the default value), but this isn't one of them.

For more information about `VLOOKUP`, consult the relevant Microsoft Office Support page [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Comment: Many thanks! I am so close to making this work, I can taste it! However, it is not a working spreadsheet as of this moment. My training in coding goes back to RPG, and COBOL learned back in the punch card days of the early 1980's - hence I believe I try to make things even more difficult than it already is.. but you're a gentleman and a scholar! I appreciate the help. It works like a charm